# R adding regression coeffcients to data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of dataframes that contains many subsets of data (470ish). I am trying to run a regression on each of them and add the regression coefficients to a dataframe. The dataframe will contain the coefficients for all dependent variables on each subgroup. I tried iterating with a for loop but obviously that is not the right way. I think the solution has something to do with lapply?

```
for (i in ListOfTraining){


    lm(JOB_VOLUME ~  FEB+MAR+APR+MAY+JUN+JUL+AUG+SEP+OCT+NOV+DEC        data=ListOfTraining[[i]])

}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using the `for` loop, if you prefer. Your problem is that the results aren't being saved to an object as the loop progresses. You can see the below for an example using the built-in `mtcars` dataframe.

(This first example is revised based on OP's request for an example of how to also extract the R squared value.)

```
ListOfTraining <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
results <- list()

for (i in seq_along(ListOfTraining)) {
  lm_obj <- lm(disp ~ qsec, data = ListOfTraining[[i]])
  tmp <- c(lm_obj$coefficients, summary(lm_obj)$r.squared)
  names(tmp)[length(tmp)] <- "r.squared"
  results[[i]] <- tmp
}

results <- do.call(rbind, results)
results
```

You can also rewrite the `for` loop using `lapply` as demoed below.

```
ListOfTraining <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
results <- list()

results <- lapply(ListOfTraining, function(x) {
  lm(disp ~ qsec, data = x)$coefficients
})

results <- do.call(rbind, results)
results
```

Finally, you can use the `plyr` package's `ldply` function which will convert the list applied outputs into a dataframe automatically (if possible).

```
ListOfTraining <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
results <- plyr::ldply(ListOfTraining, function(x) {
  lm(disp ~ qsec, data = x)$coefficients
})
results
```

Comment: Great thanks. I used the for loop and it worked perfectly. If I wanted to add the r-squared value as a column to the new data frame with all the coefficients, how would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The function `tidy` from package `broom` handles this nicely.

```
library(dplyr)          # bind_rows is more efficient than do.call(rbind, ...)
library(broom)          # put statistics into data.frame
bind_rows(lapply(ListOfTraining, function(dat)
    tidy(lm(JOB_VOLUME ~ FEB+MAR+APR+MAY+JUN+JUL+AUG+SEP+OCT+NOV+DEC, data=dat))))
```

Example

```
dataList <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)  # list of data.frames by number of cylinders
lapply(dataList, function(dat) tidy(lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data=dat))) %>%  # fit models
  bind_rows() %>%                                                        # combine into one data.frame
  mutate(model=rep(1:length(dataList), each=3))                          # add a model ID column
#          term     estimate   std.error   statistic      p.value model
# 1 (Intercept) 43.040057552 4.235724713 10.16120274 7.531962e-06     1
# 2        disp -0.119536016 0.036945788 -3.23544366 1.195900e-02     1
# 3          hp -0.046091563 0.047423668 -0.97191054 3.595602e-01     1
# 4 (Intercept) 20.151209478 6.938235241  2.90437104 4.392508e-02     2
# 5        disp  0.001796527 0.020195109  0.08895852 9.333909e-01     2
# 6          hp -0.006032441 0.034597750 -0.17435935 8.700522e-01     2
# 7 (Intercept) 24.044775630 4.045729006  5.94324919 9.686231e-05     3
# 8        disp -0.018627566 0.009456903 -1.96973225 7.456584e-02     3
# 9          hp -0.011315585 0.012572498 -0.90002676 3.873854e-01     3
```

Alternatively, you could bind the data.frames beforehand, assuming they have the same columns.  Then, fit models using `lmList` from `nlme` package.

```
## Combine list of data.frames into one data.frame with a factor variable
lengths <- sapply(dataList, nrow)  # in case data.frames have different num. rows
dat <- dataList %>% bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(group=rep(1:length(dataList), times=lengths))  # group id column

library(nlme)  # lmList()
models <- lmList(mpg ~ disp + hp | group, data=dat)  # make models, grouped by group
models$coefficients
#   (Intercept)         disp           hp
# 1    43.04006 -0.119536016 -0.046091563
# 2    20.15121  0.001796527 -0.006032441
# 3    24.04478 -0.018627566 -0.011315585
```

Comment: Instead of arbitrary model #s you could pull the names of the data.frames from the list with the final line: `mutate(model=rep(names(dataList), each=3))`

Comment: @SamFirke good idea, I wish there was a way for `bind_rows` to create an id column automatically, but it seems it hasn't been implemented

Comment: Let's hope that functionality is added.  Looks like it is in discussion at least: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/pull/825

Answer (score 1):

Your current code runs the regression, but does not do anything with the results (inside of a loop they are not even autoprinted), so they are just discarded.  You need to have some structure to save the results into.

The following code will create a matrix of coefficients (assuming that all the regressions run without error and the number of final coefficients is the same):

```
my.coef <- sapply( ListOfTraining, function(dat) { 
    coef(lm( JOB_VOLUME ~ FEB+MAR+APR+MAY+JUN+JUL+AUG+SEP+OCT+NOV+DEC,
             data=dat) )
})
```

The matrix can then be converted to a data frame (you could also use `lapply` and convert to a data frame, but I think the `sapply` option is probably a little simpler).