# Sequentially store the results of a series of regressions into a dataframe

Tags: r, function, regression

Suppose I want to run a series of regressions, like so:

```
summary(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars))
summary(lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars))
summary(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))
```

I want to create a data frame that contains the estimates and standard errors of each of these outputs, preferably with the variable name included. So the ultimate output should look like this:

```
Variable  Beta  Coeff
cyl       -2.8  .32
disp      -.04  .004
wt        -5.3  .56
```

I presume it will require a function. Any ideas out there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143423/r-adding-regression-coeffcients-to-data-frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way would be to use the `purrr` and `broom` packages in the `tidyverse`.

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)
cols <- c("cyl", "disp", "wt")

map_df(cols, ~lm(reformulate(.x, "mpg"), data=mtcars) %>% tidy())
#   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 (Intercept)  37.9      2.07        18.3  8.37e-18
# 2 cyl          -2.88     0.322       -8.92 6.11e-10
# 3 (Intercept)  29.6      1.23        24.1  3.58e-21
# 4 disp         -0.0412   0.00471     -8.75 9.38e-10
# 5 (Intercept)  37.3      1.88        19.9  8.24e-19
# 6 wt           -5.34     0.559       -9.56 1.29e-10
```

This gives you some extra info but you could easily filter it out with `dplyr` if you like.

Comment: This is brilliant. OK I'm going to push you here. What if my Independent Variable names are sequentially labeled, like "Var_1", "Var_2", "Var_3." Is there a way to do this same process without typing each of the names individually?

Comment: You can build your vector of cols however you want. Your example would just be `cols <- paste0("Var_", 1:3)`

Comment: Nice and simple! Thank you.

Comment: One final (probably simple) followup, since I've never dealt with this kind of code before: where in this equation would I place covariates? I tried:

map_df(cols, ~lm(reformulate(.x + drat, "mpg"), data=mtcars) %>% tidy())

Comment: Well, I suggest you start by checking out the `?reformulate` help page. You need to pass in a character vector of column names. With `map_df`, `.x` will be one of the names from `cols`. You add values to a vector with `c()`, not `+`.

Comment: Got it. Easy. paste0("Var_", 1:3, "+ Covariate"). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be loop through the columns of interest, `paste` to create a formula in `lm`, `tidy` the output, `slice` away the first row, and `select` the columns of interest

```
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)
map_df(c("cyl", "disp", "wt"), ~
      lm(paste0("mpg ~ ", .x), data = mtcars) %>% 
          tidy %>% 
          slice(-1) %>% 
          select(Variable = term, Beta = estimate, Coeff = std.error))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Variable    Beta   Coeff
#  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 cyl      -2.88   0.322  
#2 disp     -0.0412 0.00471
#3 wt       -5.34   0.559
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
t(sapply(c("cyl", "disp", "wt"), function(x) 
   summary(lm(paste0("mpg ~ ", x), data = mtcars))$coefficients[-1, 1:2]))
```